# I have a 50GB server SSD and 40G ram, running Ubuntu, my tmpfs is taking 2 partitions of 15GB of my SSD?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, tmpfs

How do I get some space back? I have no space.

Edit: Clarification, I did run at least a few different Conda environments, could then be the source of this tmpfs files ?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  920K  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        49G   47G  2.0G  96% /
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/126
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop2       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop3       99M   99M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/127
/dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
```

Comment: tmpfs is memory based ... it is not on the SSD ... something else is using up your disk space

Comment: Delete temp files, log files etc. What about `systemd`'s journal files? Try `journalctl --vacuum-time=1week` or longer time periods if need be.

Comment: @RudiC tried `journalctl --vacuum-time=1week` prompt:  _Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /var/log/journal/969f2e744da94a9061d1b0f15034836c._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're out of space but have difficulties matching file systems to devices. So first things first: your 50GB SSD seems to be /dev/sda1 - this is its device name. And it is mounted on / - this is the root directory. So `cd /` to root directory and check usage per next directory level with `du -h --max-depth=1`

All other devices are neither yours nor do they consume memory. All tmpfs reside in RAM and they have an assigned maximum size. They do not occupy it until they're filled with content. Cross check with command `free` or monitor with `top` (exit with ESC- or Q-key).

Devices /dev/loopX seem to be re-mounted outside content, e.g. unencrypted versions of encrypted devices or in your case something related to your host provider. They're reported full because they're actually no devices like a hard disk. They're purely virtual.

You can easily check whether there's space left: you can still log in through SSH or similar. Thus log files and other management data can be written.

Meanwhile check your favorite source of information for the so called Linux Standard Base. It explains basic Linux filesystem layout and guidelines. Also have a look at Linux file system types, esp. tmpfs and loop devices.

Comment: No, it's the other way round. 2G are free.

Comment: as pointed, 2gb are free, not in use.

Comment: Absolutely right, fixed it and suggested du/ disk usage command to dig in deeper. 50GByte is not very much at all for a Linux system. When running update commands space will be consumed by downloaded packages. Following Linux Standard Base this could be in /var. Also varieties of kernel modules in /lib/modules could waste space.